# How to navigate pages without unload event

Tags: javascript, html

I find that in the https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ and few other top HTML5 website, the load/unload/onbeforeunload events are not begin fired but the URL in location bar will change. The the browser history update.

What is the name of this skill? and how could it be done in my own app?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pushState` is what you are looking for

[check this question :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

I hope this helps.